# Open a file in another window without blocking subsequent calls/concurrent calls from the view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, async-await

In one of our page we do have a file view option. While clicking on the file we are calling a controller action method which returns a FileResult. This file is showing in a different tab. The issue is because of the file size, its taking some seconds to load the file, until the file is returned from server the other operations cannot be done from the UI. The subsequent requests are hitting only when this operation is completed. Is there any way to open this file without affecting the subsequent requests?

The current approach we are using here is below.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<FileResult> OpenAttachment(string attachid)
{
    var attachment = await Task.Run(() => this._commService.OpenAttachment(attachid));
   
    if (attachment == null)
    {
        throw new PnnCustomExceptions("File not found");
    }

    attachment.FileName = attachment.FileName.AddAttachmentNameExtension(attachment.MimeType);

    var cd = new ContentDisposition
    {
        Inline = true,
        FileName = attachment.FileName
    };

    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader(CoreConstants.ContentDisposition, cd.ToString());
    Response.AddHeader(CoreConstants.WindowTarget, CoreConstants.WindowTargetBlank);
    Response.BufferOutput = false;
    return File(attachment.Data, attachment.MimeType);
}
```

Is there any way we can do this in MVC?

Comment: How is the UI "blocked" if the file is opened in another tab? Why can't you go back to your original tab and continue working? Does the browser seize up? Because if so, that's not something your backend can fix, that's a client machine issue.

Comment: So how many requests can your server handle? If you fire a request that simply does `await Task.Delay(100000)`, is your backend still unable to handle any other requests in the meantime? That's likely not a code-specific question, but rather one of hardware. Web servers really need the ability to handle more than one request at a time. Either the backend server is woefully underresourced, or the file generation is disproportionately heavy that it should not be done on the backend server directly. Or maybe you're just focusing on a local debug session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to concurrent requests in the same session. We have added a session state behavior in our controller to fix this issue. Since this controller never going to update the session we have added a decorator like below in the controller

```
  [SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
  public class AttachmentController
{
....
}
```

Since this controller is decorated with session readonly, it wont queue the concurrent requests.